# How to make left time count backward

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Example is about groupon.com. As we know it say time left for certain products and counts every second. So I can do it with javascript but server side should I update it through Ajax all products left time attribute every second or how to update it in server without AJAX

Anybody knows?
1) Something should update my products timeLeft on server?
I can't find that something.

Only thing I can do is update them through ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and best way to do count-downs is client-side. Trying to store and update that kind of information is a *huge* waste of time, space, and processing.

Basically, your database should have the ending time on it, and that will get sent to the client. Then the client will update every second using javascript:

```
var timeLeft = product.endTime - currentTime;
```

Then you can update `timeLeft` every second.

Comment: let's say product.endTime=tomorrow, Javascript is updating on client_side but what about server_side, who is updating server side. Thanks

Comment: This assumes that the client's system clock is correct. I'd recommend having the same information in the database, but instead of sending that directly to the client, send the "time left" to the client so that his system clock is of no impact.

Comment: Let's forget about client. Which class or model is updating my products leftTime on seerver

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing `timeLeft` on the server. It will end up being way too much processing to be any good. You can use PHP to get the initial time, `$initTimeLeft = $endTime-time()` (or whatever), and then let JS calculate seconds to subtract from that.

Comment: That column should not exist in the database. You only need to store an expire time on the product. Then your server can have a line to calculate `timeLeft` on request. Then JS will update that every second **without any requests** on the client-side. When the page refreshes, the line in the code will re-calculate `timeLeft` and the same thing will happen.